# Cosmos DB - Deleting a document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I delete an individual record from Cosmos DB?

I can select using SQL syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM collection1
WHERE (collection1._ts > 0)
```

And sure enough all documents (analogous to rows?) are returned

However this doesn't work when I attempt to delete

```
DELETE
FROM collection1
WHERE (collection1._ts > 0)
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The DocumentDB API's SQL is specifically for *querying*. That is, it only provides `SELECT`, not `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Those operations are fully supported, but require REST (or SDK) calls. For example, with .net, you'd call `DeleteDocumentAsync()` or `ReplaceDocumentAsync()`, and in node.js, this would be a call to `deleteDocument()` or `replaceDocument()`.

In your particular scenario, you could run your `SELECT` to identify documents for deletion, then make "delete" calls, one per document (or, for efficiency and transactionality, pass an array of documents to delete, into a stored procedure).

Comment: Ah ok, another piece of the puzzle falls into place. I'm using Python and can see DeleteDocument(). Thanks!

Comment: is this possible for java version of SDK?

Comment: @blackuprise - yes, this is fully supported in Java. You'll find a `deleteDocument()` method of `DocumentClient`.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Can deleteDocument be used without partition key? I am using a stored procedure but it is not working.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is probably by using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/storage-explorer). After connecting you can drill down to a container of choice, select a document and then delete it. You can find additional tools for Cosmos DB on https://gotcosmos.com/tools.

[image: Use Azure Storage Explorer to connect to Cosmos DB]

Comment: Is there a way to delete multiple documents at once in Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Even easier, use the Data Explorer built into the Azure Portal web page.

Comment: the Data Explorer built into the Azure Portal web page doesn't understand delete

Answer (score 11):

Another option to consider is the time to live (TTL).  You can turn this on for a collection and then set an expiration for the documents.  The documents will be cleaned up automatically for you as they expire.

Comment: easiest solution i've found so far

Comment: Doesn't work for me. After settings TTL to 1sec. the documents were not visible, but after going back to TTL turned off the documents appeared again.

Comment: @DOminikMinc maybe you need to wait little longer. It takes some time for the cloud to remove the items.

Answer (score 7):

Create a stored procedure with the following code:

```
/**
 * A Cosmos DB stored procedure that bulk deletes documents for a given query.
 * Note: You may need to execute this stored procedure multiple times (depending whether the stored procedure is able to delete every document within the execution timeout limit).
 *
 * @function
 * @param {string} query - A query that provides the documents to be deleted (e.g. "SELECT c._self FROM c WHERE c.founded_year = 2008"). Note: For best performance, reduce the # of properties returned per document in the query to only what's required (e.g. prefer SELECT c._self over SELECT * )
 * @returns {Object.<number, boolean>} Returns an object with the two properties:
 *   deleted - contains a count of documents deleted
 *   continuation - a boolean whether you should execute the stored procedure again (true if there are more documents to delete; false otherwise).
 */
function bulkDeleteStoredProcedure(query) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var responseBody = {
        deleted: 0,
        continuation: true
    };

    // Validate input.
    if (!query) throw new Error("The query is undefined or null.");

    tryQueryAndDelete();

    // Recursively runs the query w/ support for continuation tokens.
    // Calls tryDelete(documents) as soon as the query returns documents.
    function tryQueryAndDelete(continuation) {
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, retrievedDocs, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (retrievedDocs.length > 0) {
                // Begin deleting documents as soon as documents are returned form the query results.
                // tryDelete() resumes querying after deleting; no need to page through continuation tokens.
                //  - this is to prioritize writes over reads given timeout constraints.
                tryDelete(retrievedDocs);
            } else if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                // Else if the query came back empty, but with a continuation token; repeat the query w/ the token.
                tryQueryAndDelete(responseOptions.continuation);
            } else {
                // Else if there are no more documents and no continuation token - we are finished deleting documents.
                responseBody.continuation = false;
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        });

        // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
    }

    // Recursively deletes documents passed in as an array argument.
    // Attempts to query for more on empty array.
    function tryDelete(documents) {
        if (documents.length > 0) {
            // Delete the first document in the array.
            var isAccepted = collection.deleteDocument(documents[0]._self, {}, function (err, responseOptions) {
                if (err) throw err;

                responseBody.deleted++;
                documents.shift();
                // Delete the next document in the array.
                tryDelete(documents);
            });

            // If we hit execution bounds - return continuation: true.
            if (!isAccepted) {
                response.setBody(responseBody);
            }
        } else {
            // If the document array is empty, query for more documents.
            tryQueryAndDelete();
        }
    }
}
```

And execute it using your partition key (example: null) and a query to select the documents (example: SELECT c._self FROM c to delete all).

Based on [Delete Documents from CosmosDB based on condition through Query Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774835/delete-documents-from-cosmosdb-based-on-condition-through-query-explorer?rq=1)

Comment: @marc_s do I need to use the same format for the query (e.g. SELECT c._self FROM c) or can I do (SELECT * FROM c). In addition, is the partition key the name of the partition key?

Comment: Trying this for hours now. Works great if I call it from the Azure portal, and does not fail when I call it from a client C# app. But never deletes any records. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I delete records from my client app? Any examples incl. c# client code?

Comment: Unable to delete any record using this. Returns 0 docs deleted.

Comment: This does not work from either the Azure portal or the Cosmos emulator. It returns 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use [bulkDeleteStoredProcedure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/blob/1dbe69893d09a5da29328c14ec087ef168038009/samples/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js) using .net Cosmos [SDK V3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3).

ContinuationFlag has to be used because of the execution bounds.

```
private async Task<int> ExecuteSpBulkDelete(string query, string partitionKey)
    {
        var continuationFlag = true;
        var totalDeleted = 0;
        while (continuationFlag)
        {
            StoredProcedureExecuteResponse<BulkDeleteResponse> result = await _container.Scripts.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<BulkDeleteResponse>(
                "spBulkDelete", // your sproc name
                new PartitionKey(partitionKey), // pk value
                new[] { sql });

            var response = result.Resource;
            continuationFlag = response.Continuation;
            var deleted = response.Deleted;
            totalDeleted += deleted;
            Console.WriteLine($"Deleted {deleted} documents ({totalDeleted} total, more: {continuationFlag}, used {result.RequestCharge}RUs)");
        }

        return totalDeleted;
    }
```

and response model:

```
public class BulkDeleteResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("deleted")]
    public int Deleted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("continuation")]
    public bool Continuation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a single document from cosmos db using c# by below method -
You can use the below method with cosmosdb container instance.

CustomerContainer.DeleteItemAsync(id, new PartitionKey("AnyValueofPartitionKey"))

**T** -> Is the type of item in the container.
**id** -> Is the guid of the item to be deleted. (for this you can first fetch the items from cosmosdb using select query)
**AnyValueofPartitionKey** - Most of the times we create Partition Key with cosmos db containers, so in this you have to provide a value for that key for ex - My key is customerCity, so I provided "Goa".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Node.JS API, you can use the command:

```
container.item(id, partitionId).delete()
```