# Azure Cosmos DB SQL API UPDATE statement - don't replace whole document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Can I write an `UPDATE` statement for Azure Cosmos DB? The SQL API supports queries, but what about updates?

In particular, I am looking to update documents without having to retrieve the whole document. I have the ID for the document and I know the exact path I want to update within the document. For example, say that my document is

```
{
  "id": "9e576f8b-146f-4e7f-a68f-14ef816e0e50",
  "name": "Fido",
  "weight": 35,
  "breed": "pomeranian",
  "diet": {
    "scoops": 3,
    "timesPerDay": 2
  }
}
```

and I want to update `diet.timesPerDay` to 1 where the ID is `"9e576f8b-146f-4e7f-a68f-14ef816e0e50"`. Can I do that using the Azure SQL API without completely replacing the document?

Comment: FYI related to your question (though not exactly the same) - an answer going into more detail regarding `select` vs `update / insert / delete` along with sdk calls to deal with those (though the updates done via SDK are still done as full document replacement, as Nick pointed out in his answer) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873986/272109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Patch API for partial updates.
Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update

Comment: That requires a slightly different auth token to achieve.  I would say this should not be the answer.   The question here is probably a user talking about using SDK access with queries rather than Azure API.

Answer (score 26):

The Cosmos DB SQL language only supports the `Select` statement.

Partially updating a document isn't supported via the sql language or the SQL API.

People have made it clear that that's a feature they want so there is a highly upvoted request for it that can be found here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document

Microsoft has already started to work on that so the only thing you can do is wait.

Comment: You could use a stored procedure. E.g., [this sproc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/blob/1dbe69893d09a5da29328c14ec087ef168038009/samples/stored-procedures/update.js) is similar to MongoDB's `update` operator.

Comment: A private preview is now under way. You can sign up here https://aka.ms/cosmosdbpatch

Comment: Starting with November 2021 partial document updates are now possible with .NET, Java, and Node SDK, as well as with stored procedures.

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate more on this, Updating partially a document in **`CosmosDb`** on the server isn’t possible, instead you can do whatever you need to do in the memory.In order to literally **`UPDATE`** the document, you will have to to retrieve the entire document from the CosmosDb, update the **`property/properties`** that you need to update and then call the ‘Replace’ method in the CosmosDb SDK to replace the document in question. Alternatively you can also use ‘Upsert’ which checks if the document already exists and performs an **`‘Insert’`** if true or ‘Replace’ if **`false.`**

**NOTE :** Make sure you have the latest version of the document before you commit an update!

**UPDATE :**

CosmosDB support for Partial Update is GAed. You can read more from  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update)

Comment: "is working" might not be the most accurate state, it has been 1 year and 7 months since and still nothing

Comment: this is so behind, even MongoDB can run updateMany command

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since the original question was posed, but this entry is the primary search result.

We can now use the following operation to update only part of the record.

Container.PatchItemAsync

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.patchitemasync?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

As of 25.05.2021 this feature is available in private preview and will hopefully be in GA soon.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/partial-document-update-for-azure-cosmos-db-in-private-preview/

Answer (score -3):

Use Robo3T to update/delete multiple records with mongo db commands. Make sure your query includes the partition key.

```
db.getCollection('ListOfValues').updateMany({type:'PROPOSAL', key:"CITI"},{$set: {"key":"CITIBANK"}})

db.getCollection('ListOfValues').deleteMany({type:'PROPOSAL', key:"CITI"})
```

Comment: User specified SQL API

Comment: The question specifies nothing about mongo db