# Is it possible to delete a record from cosmos db azure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to delete a record from cosmos db. I dont want to write any scripts. Is it possible to direct hit this query from cosmos db UI from azure portal

```
DELETE * FROM c WHERE c.id = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873986/272109), under the question I marked this as duplicate of, where I've provided details directly related to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Set based operations including Delete are not supported on Azure CosmosDB. You could consider upvoting for it [`here`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6346033-set-based-operations-insert-update-delete)

However you could delete the documents from portal by selecting them or using SDK

Comment: Note that the question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46871925/272109), where I've already provided a detailed answer.