# cosmos db best way to delete document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I delete item from cosmos Db document. I am trying below query but no luck.

delete from c
where c.ode = '21423423'

Comment: You can't delete items by query. You need to use the REST API (or any SDK implementing the API) and delete each item using it's `id` and partition key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cosmos DB - Deleting a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871925/cosmos-db-deleting-a-document)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SQL API does not provide facilities for delete, this must be done through the REST API, Storage Explorer etc.

[In addition, I saw the official reply that the delete function is not yet supported.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/812403/can-i-delete-document-from-azure-cosmos-db-using-s.html)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Also, this question is a duplicate of an already-answered question (as posted in my link under the question).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Node.JS API, you can use the command:

```
container.item(id, partitionId).delete()
```

I recognize that there are many other APIs, but when I was trying to figure out how to do this for NodeJS this question came up but did not help me and this is the only API I know how to use / have time to answer.